# How to load image from URL in ccsprite

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

I am showing image from URL in CCSprite. There are many images and hence i need to load image very quickly.
I have written my code which worked fine in simulator but crashed on iPad. Now i can't understand anything from the device log.

My code:

```
NSData *d = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[Data valueForKey:[NSString   stringWithFormat:@"%d", idx]]]];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", documentsDirectory, string];
BOOL didWrite = [d writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
CCSprite * facebookImage = [[CCSprite alloc] initWithFile:filePath] ;
```

Here I am saving my image in file and giving those content to CCSprite.

now the image from URL is fetching properly in simulator but on device this code crashes. 
P.S : there are other ways too but they didn't work that well so i preferred this method over NSRequest etc.

Answer (score 0):

Set a breakpoint, single-step through the code. Write probably fails because your path contains a space before the filename (format string: `"%@ %@"`), or because string is nil.

Write failsafe code: you already have a `didWrite` flag, you should have an if clause that creates the sprite when write (and download) succeeded, otherwise log the error and perhaps create a placeholder sprite.

Comment: Hi, Thanx for your answer but it all worked fine in simulator and crashed on app as mentioned in my question. how to put breakpoint then? also this thing is for sure that file name contains data. hence worked on simulator.Did u mean that commonest problem of case sensitive stuff due to which app often crashes on device?

Comment: if you don't know how to set a breakpoint, read the xcode docs. This is as fundamental to programming as the semicolon.

Comment: I know how to put breakpoint in an app, which is something most basic in programming i know that. But i meant if it crashes on device then there is no way i can test putting breakpoint in Xcode. Note: it works on simulator. NO point if i put breakpoint while running on simulator.

Comment: put the breakpoint before the line that crashes, then single step and check return values ... btw you haven't said on which line it crashes

Answer (score 0):

To display image from URL in CCSprite I have now changed my approach.

```
UIImage *uiimage2 = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
CCSprite * facebookImage = [[CCSprite alloc]initWithCGImage:uiimage2.CGImage key:string];
```

Hope this answer helps someone.